# Is it ok to use Bottom Nav Bar with Tabs for sub-level?

Tags: material-design, sidebar, tab, bottom-navigation

I am trying to design and app with Material design which has 6 top level destinations and 4 of them have sub-levels.

1. Is it ok to use Bottom nav bar for 5 of them and put 6th one in side navs along with some more options like profile, logout, & help & policy?
2. Is it ok to use top tabs for sub levels along with bottom nav and side nav?
3. Is it ok to use same design for iOS apps as well?

Comment: Could you add a wireframe, mockup or a screenshot to make it easier to visualize what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly ok to use bottom nav bar, and also recommended to do so considering the size(height) of current smart phones.

Thumb is the primary finger most users use for single hand interactions and bottom navigations make it easy for the thumb to reach almost all primary  menu options without a need of another hand.

## Examples:

Facebook, WhatsApp, Youtube:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I am ok to use bottom nav bar, but is it ok to have Tabs along with it?

Comment: @GauravGaikwad If the tabs are making things more usable and helping your business in any form, then yes, tabs are ok to use. Just style them in a way so that it doesn't look weird.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, lets understand the use of tabs and navigation drawer.

Tabs are used when you wish to display data of similar importance simultaneously to user. while navigation drawer is used to keep data that is important but not very related to each other.
SO it is better if you first group your information in a related pattern.Then put the most un related information in navigation drawer.
You can user cards for showing level two grouping. These cards will have the name of the category and will expand as you click on any one of them. This way you can keep your UI clean and add more sub categories in future if needed. 
For reference check the foll. ans. -https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/111223/105043

It is okay if you keep the same layout in iOS as well, but with fewer modification. for additional resource you can check the folllowing link:
https://medium.com/@jrejaud/developing-for-android-vs-ios-navigation-patterns-c0e11286562c

Comment: But would be ok to use top tabs for sub levels along with bottom nav (top level destinations) and side nav?